# When casting a timestamp to date yields a (Date + 1)

Tags: sql, date, datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

In Google Spanner, I am trying to cast some timestamps to date, when I found this issue.

When executing the script below:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM CAST("2019-01-01T07:56:34Z" AS TIMESTAMP))
```

I get an output `2018-12-31`, rather than `2019-01-01`.

How should I parse it to the exact date?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend explicitly specifying a time zone, for instance by using the [DATE](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#date) function. Otherwise, America/Los_Angeles is the default timezone, which is offset by -8 hours with respect to the timestamp timezone you're providing. The timestamp literal you provided specifies Z (Zulu time) as the timezone offset.

```
# Default timezone.
select DATE(TIMESTAMP "2019-01-01T07:56:34Z", "America/Los_Angeles");
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
| 2018-12-31 |
+------------+

# GMT aka Zulu time zone for both the timestamp and the date extraction.
select DATE(TIMESTAMP "2019-01-01T07:56:34Z", "+00:00");
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
| 2019-01-01 |
+------------+
```

Comment: yes this can be used, but this might create an issue for other timestamps.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what issue it would create?

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, when I run it, I get the correct date.  This is clearly a timezone issue.

If you want to extract the date from the string as is, then use substring to get the date component and convert to a date:

```
CAST(SUBSTR('2019-01-01T07:56:34Z', 1, 10) as DATE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to use like below :

```
select CAST('2019-01-01T07:56:34Z' AS date)
```

Comment: Could not cast literal "2019-01-01T07:56:34Z" to type DATE at line 1, column 13

Comment: direct CASTing produces this issue in Spanner